# BJT switching circuit with a capacitor as a load

Tags: capacitor, digital-logic, bjt

The circuit schematic and the resulting waveforms  look like this:
[image]

It is clear to me that when the transistor turns off, the capacitor starts charging up as:
\$u_{CL}\left ( t \right )=E_c(1-e^{\frac{-t}{R_C C_L}})\$. However, I've also been given this relation(with no explanation whatsoever):
\$U_{CL}\left ( t \right )=U_{CE} +E_c e^{\frac{-t}{R_{CE} C_L}}\$. The parameter \$R_{CE}\$ seems to represent the BJT's internal resistance. Another thing that's been bugging me is the abrubt change in capacitor voltage as the transistor goes into ON mode. Wouldn't this imply that the power dissipated \$\rightarrow \infty\$, since power is the time derivative of the energy stored in the capacitor.

Comment: To answer the second question: theoretically infinite current but in practice both the capacitor and transistor have some internal resistance. It's hard to answer the first part without knowing what \$U_{CE}\$ and \$R_{CE}\$ refer to. Is the equation for the same diagram?

Comment: @transistor Indeed it is

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that \$U_{CE}\$ is the collector-emitter potential of the BJT. But then the equation is wrong because \$U_{CL}\$, \$U_{CE}\$ and \$u_{out}\$ all measure the potential between the same terminals so they are identically equal. You need to look for some explanation in your text that tells you one of these symbols means something different from what it might be expected to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression gives how the capacitor is charging from 0V to \$E_C\$ through the resistor \$R_C\$. So time constant = \$R_CC_L\$. hence the expression:
$$u_{CL}\left ( t \right )=E_c(1-e^{\frac{-t}{R_C C_L}})$$

After the capacitor is charged to \$E_C\$ the input changed and transistor becomes 'on'. Now the capacitor will discharge from \$E_C\$ to \$U_{CE_{sat}}\$ through the transistor, equivalent resistance of which is \$R_{CE}\$. Where \$U_{CE_{sat}}\$ is the collector-emitter voltage when transistor is in saturation. So the discharging of capacitor can be expressed as:

$$u_{CL}\left ( t \right )=U_{CE_{sat}} +(E_c-U_{CE_{sat}}) e^{\frac{-t}{R_{CE} C_L}}$$

> 1st expression is the charging equation.

\$U_{CE_{sat}}\$ is usually a small voltage (0.2-0.3V) compared to \$E_C\$, many a people approximates \$E_c-U_{CE_{sat}}\$ to \$E_C\$. And in that case this becomes your second expression.

> 2nd expression is the discharging equation.

From the two expressions above, one can see that the charging and discharging time depends on the capacitance and resistance values through which it charge/discharges. Now if the value of \$R_{CE}\$ is less than that of \$R_C\$, the time taken for the capacitor to discharge fully will be less than that of the time required to charge. I think in your case, the discharging time few times smaller than charging time and hence in the plot, it looks like an abrupt transition.

Answer (score 2):

The second equation would represent the discharging, however it's *really* not a very good approximation of a how a BJT behaves. Also, it ignores the resistor Rc, presumably under the assumption that

\$R_{CE} \approx \frac {R_{CE}\cdot R_C}{R_{CE}+R_C}\$

The BJT will act more like a constant current sink until the capacitor voltage drops near ground. The actual current will depend on the gain of the transistor with a given base current (and Vce), and it is certainly not infinite. Below is an accurate simulation of a 2N4401 with 0.1mA of base current switched on at t=0+ discharging a 10nF capacitor with 10K to +10V.

[image]

As you can see, after the initial delay the discharge is very linear until it gets down near the Vce(sat) of about 67mV. The collector current looks like this:

[image]

It goes up to ~19.5mA +/-15% for most of the duration of the discharge- the current gain (\$h_{FE}\$ a.k.a. \$\beta\$) of the transistor is about 200 under those conditions.

Comment: Where does the equation \$R_{CE} \approx \frac {R_{CE}\cdot R_C}{R_{CE}+R_C}\$ come from?

Comment: *If* the transistor behaved like a resistor (which it doesn't, not even a bit) then the parallel combination of the 'resistance' between emitter and collector and the load resisance Rce||Rc would determine the time constant. But it doesn't and it doesn't. If Rce << Rc then the parallel combination would be close to Rce.